# Reverse children elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to reorder some children elements with defined class and maintain the old order of the others that doesn't have the class. I have other sub elements

Code - html

```
<ul class="menu_dinamico">   
<li class="reverseMenu"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
 <li class="reverseMenu">Item 2</li>
      <ul>
      <li>item 2.1</li>
      <li>item 2.2</li>
        </ul>
 <li class="reverseMenu">Item 3</li>
 <li class="reverseMenu">Item 4</li>
 <li>Item 4.5</li>
 <li>Item 5</li> </ul>
```

Code - javascript

```
$.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
var list = $('.menu_dinamico');
var listItems = list.children('.reverseMenu');
list.prepend(listItems.get().reverse());
```

The result

- item 4
- item 3
- item 2
- [item 1](http://#)
- item 2.1
- item 2.2
- item 4.5
- item 5

**The result wanted**

- item 4
- item 3
- item 2

  - item 2.1
  - item 2.2
- [item 1](http://#)
- item 4.5
- item 5

P.s: I have to maintain the html structure like links, attributes etc.

Any clues? Thanks!

**Edit:**

After @bubicsaszar response I realized that my question was incomplete because my list can have infinite sub lists and their structure must be preserved.

Comment: Thank you! I don't see it coming! It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, if the constant items always in the end of the list:

```
$.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
var list = $('.menu_dinamico');
var listItems = list.children('.reverseMenu');
list.prepend(listItems.get().reverse());
```

Comment: I had a problem. In fact my question was not complete. I edited it.

Comment: could you help me?

Comment: in this case, I think you only have to change your markup (the sub lists should be inside the li tags)

https://jsfiddle.net/z4Lgqb0h/

Comment: Yes! I wrote on computer. I didn't see this. Thank you.